# EF Core/Automapper Projection causes NullReferenceError

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper, ef-core-5.0

i'm using automampper and EF core 5, and having an issue trying to get a count of a child list when using a projection. If i try and get the list of child objects it works fine, my view model is here:

```cs
public class CurrentRunningBatchView
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public int BatchNo { get; set; }
        public int PropertiesSearching { get; set; }
        public int PropertiesSearched { get; set; }
        public ClassificationTypeEnum ClassificationType { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EstimatedFinishTime { get; set; }
        public List<Classification> Classifications { get; set; }
    }
```

my map is here:

```cs
public class CurrentRunningBatchViewProfile : Profile
    {
        public CurrentRunningBatchViewProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<ClassificationBatch, CurrentRunningBatchView>()
                //.ConvertUsing<BatchConverter>()
                .ForMember(c => c.Classifications, o => o.MapFrom(s=> s.Classifications.Take(10)))
                //.ForMember(c => c.ClassificationType, o => o.MapFrom(s => ClassificationTypeEnum.FromValue(s.)))
                .ForMember(s => s.PropertiesSearching, d => d.MapFrom(s => s.Classifications.Count))
                //.ForMember(s => s.PropertiesSearched, d=> d.MapFrom(s => s.Classifications.Count(c => c.ClassificationResults.Any())))
                //.AfterMap<SortCurrentRunningEstimatationMappingAction>();
                ;
        }
    }
```

The classifications property works fine and is only in there to prove it works, and if i comment out the propertiessearch line, then it works fine.
The query expression in the debug code looks fine:

```cs
DbSet<ClassificationBatch>()
    .Where(b => b.EndDate == null && b.StartDate != null)
    .Include("Classifications")
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Select(dtoClassificationBatch => new CurrentRunningBatchView{
        BatchNo = dtoClassificationBatch.BatchNo,
        Classifications = dtoClassificationBatch.Classifications
            .Take(10)
            .ToList(),
        ClassificationType = dtoClassificationBatch.ClassificationType,
        Id = dtoClassificationBatch.Id,
        PropertiesSearching = dtoClassificationBatch.Classifications.Count,
        StartDate = dtoClassificationBatch.StartDate ?? 01/01/0001 00:00:00
    }
    )
    .FirstOrDefault()
```

The error i get is this:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SelectExpression.ApplyCollectionJoin(Int32 collectionIndex, Int32 collectionId, Expression innerShaper, INavigationBase navigation, Type elementType, Boolean splitQuery)
```

i'm guessing the problem lies with automapper as opposed to EF core? but i cant seem to get any data on what its doing when compiling the query expression, any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: Does it help if you add a .ToList() before the .Count?

Comment: Looks like EFC bug.

Answer (score -1):

i found the answer to my problem, in the mapping, rather than calling .Count, i needed to call .Count(), i think this is an EF thing as i took away all AutoMapper code and directly did a select on the DBContext, then transfered the working code to the AutoMapper map